# Is there some physical significance or some example to think about rows of a linear map as columns can be thought as coefficients for basis change?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

When multiplying two linear maps, one can assume physical significance for the columns of a linear map. (They would be the coefficients to transform a basis in one vector space to the basis in the other). The same would go for the multiplication of linear maps as in a transformation of the transformation of bases. [Math equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yRJP.png)

Please open the image on the link, as I don't have enough reputation to post inline images.

The Prof. mentioned this as an interesting result, and my question is whether there is some physical significance or something imaginable for the rows of a matrix (linear maps) as such?!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Let $u:E\to F$ be a linear map between two finite dimensional vector spaces.

Fix a basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ of $E$ and a basis $(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ of $F$.

Then for all $x\in E$, $u(x)=\varphi_1(x)f_1+\cdots+\varphi_m(x)f_m$, where $\varphi_i(x)\in K$ ($K$ being the base field).

It is easy to see that $\varphi_i:E\to K$ is linear. Lienar maps form $E\to K$ are called **linear forms.**  Now it is not difficult to see that the row vector $(\varphi(e_1),\ldots,\varphi_i(e_n))$ is the $i$-th row of the matrix of $u$ with respect to the two bases we fixed.

This is just because $\varphi_i(x_1e_1+\cdots+x_n e_n)=\varphi_i(e_1)x_1+\cdots+\varphi_i(e_n)x_n$.

In other words: If $M$ is the matrix of $u$ in the two bases:

- the $j$-th column represents the column vector of coordinates of $u(e_j)$ in the basis of $F$
- the $i$-row represents the linear from $x\mapsto$ $i$-th coordinate of $u(x)$ in the basis of $E$

**More formally.** Let $e_i^*:E\to K$ be the linear from defined by $e_i^*(x_1e_1+\cdots+x_ne_n)=x_i$ (it is called the $i$-th coordinate form). Then $(e_1^*,\ldots,e_n^*)$ is a basis  of $E^*=Lin(E,K)$, and for all $\varphi\in E^*$, we have $\varphi=\varphi(e_1)e_1^*+\cdots+\varphi(e_n)e_n^*$.

So to interpret to $i$-th row: look at the the linear form $\varphi_i: x\mapsto$ $i$-th coordinate of $u(x)$ in the basis of $E$. The row vector of coordinates of $\varphi_i$ in the basis $(e_1^*,\ldots,e_n^*)$ is the $i$-th row of $M$.

It is probably more enlightening to see how it works when $E=K^n,F=K^m$, when you take canonical bases. Then:

$u:x\in K^n\to (\sum_j a_{1j}x_j,\ldots,\sum_j a_{mj}x_j)\in K^m$. In this case, $\varphi_i$ is just $x\mapsto (a_{i1} \ \cdots \ a_{in})x$

**To sum up.** If there is only one thing to remember from all this abstract mumbo jumbo:

- columns represents vectors
- rows represents linear forms